# Select rows that not match all items OR match not all items

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

I have a table `A` with column `col`. I have a list of values like `val1`, `val2`, `val3`.
I need select rows when `col` does NOT contain `val1` and `val2` and `val3`, OR `col` contains less than 3 values.

First condition I understand, it's like:

```
col NOT LIKE '%val1%' AND col NOT LIKE '%val2%' AND col NOT LIKE '%val3%'
```

But I have no idea how to select less than 3 values in condition.

UPD. Example data

```
Table A

    | col
1   | sample val1
2   | sample val1 val2
3   | sample val1 val2 val3
4   | sample
5   | sample val2
6   | sample val3 val2 val1
```

Desired result:

```
    | col
1   | sample val1
2   | sample val1 val2
5   | sample val2
```

Comment: Please show some actual sample data and desired results.

Comment: @DaleK added sample data

Comment: You know of course the best solution is to properly structure your data and avoid storing multiple values in the same column?

Comment: row 4 also "has less than 3 values"?

Comment: No using `'%val1%'` could return the wrong results. For example `%Mad%` would match the whole word "Mad" but also "Madrid", "Madeline" or "Madagascar".  While technically you could probably rig something together using string functions, ultimately those options are more error prone and poor performing than a set based solution. A better option is to store the individual values in *separate* rows - instead of as delimited lists. Then queries like this will be quite simple.